# Best way to fill values in DataFrame based on row in Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a spark DataFrame with these important columns:

| test_number | test_name | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | name_2 | 8 | 17 |
| 2 |  | 0 | 0 |

The data for a given test_number appears in only one row by design, but I would like to fill up the missing data of test_name with the given value and replace zeroes likewise.
The expected table:

| test_number | test_name | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | name_1 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | name_1 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | name_2 | 8 | 17 |
| 2 | name_2 | 8 | 17 |

My approach would be to use max("value_1").over(Window.partitionBy("test_number")) for value_1 and value_2 and maybe a collect_list() approach for the missing test_names. However I would like to ask if there could be a smarter, more optimal way of doing what I described. Thank you kindly for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows with non-empty "test_name" can be selected to different data frame, and left-joined with original data:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "name_1", 5, 10),
  (1, null, 0, 0),
  (1, null, 0, 0),
  (2, "name_2", 8, 17),
  (2, null, 0, 0)
).toDF(
  "test_number", "test_name", "value_1", "value_2"
)

val replacement = df
  .where($"test_name".isNotNull)
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("test_number").orderBy("test_name")))
  .where($"row_number" === 1)

val result = df.alias("d")
  .join(replacement.alias("r"), Seq("test_number"), "left")
  .select(
    $"test_number",
    coalesce($"d.test_name", $"r.test_name").alias("test_name"),
    coalesce($"r.value_1", $"d.value_1").alias("value_1"),
    coalesce($"r.value_2", $"d.value_2").alias("value_2")
  )
```

Output is:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+
|test_number|test_name|value_1|value_2|
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+
|1          |name_1   |5      |10     |
|1          |name_1   |5      |10     |
|1          |name_1   |5      |10     |
|2          |name_2   |8      |17     |
|2          |name_2   |8      |17     |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Does coalesce work on zeros in the case of value_1 and value_2? I like the solution though

Comment: coalesce works only for nulls. If left-joined table will have nulls, original values will be used.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand for example if you have two columns, r.value_1 with 0 and d.value_1 with 5 and coalesce the two what will be the result

Comment: Value  'r.value_1' (5) will be taken. Coalesce takes first non-null value.
I put coalesce just in case when particular "test_number" will not have rows with non-null 'test_name'. You can remove coalesce if such situation will not happen.
Also please take into account condition $"test_name".isNotNull, here not-null values selected. If empty "test_name" value possible instead of null, this condition can be changed.